# mongodb aggregation framework match by nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following list of documents:

```
{
    "_id" : "Tvq579754r",
    "name": "Tom",
    "forms": {
           "PreOp":{
             "status":"closed"          
           },

           "Alert":{
             "status":"closed"          
           },

           "City":{
              "status":"closed"         
           },

          "Country":{
             "status":"closed"          
          } 
    }
},
....
{
    "_id" : "Tvq444454j",
    "name": "Jim",
    "forms": {
          "Jorney":{
             "status":"closed"          
           },

          "Women":{
             "status":"void"            
          },

         "Child":{
            "status":"closed"           
         },

         "Farm":{
           "status":"closed"            
         }  
     }
}
```

I want to filter them by their 'status' field('forms.name_of_form.status'). I need fetch all documents which don't have 'forms.name_of_form.status' equal 'void'.

Expected result is (document without voided form status):

```
{
    "_id" : "Tvq579754r",
    "name": "Tom",
    "forms": {
           "PreOp":{
             "status":"closed"          
           },

           "Alert":{
             "status":"closed"          
           },

           "City":{
              "status":"closed"         
           },

          "Country":{
             "status":"closed"          
          } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to get all documents or all _ids? Also, you need to filter out the documents that have some specific form with status "void" or **any** status "void"?

Comment: I want to get out all documents where each document has all his forms  in 'closed' status not in 'void'

Comment: Is the list of form names finite (specified)?

Comment: No, form names can be changed in future. I don't have to rely on the form names.

Comment: Can you edit with an expected result. That helps people to answer.

Comment: Updated with expected result.

Comment: Serves as a good example of structure and data usage patterns. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Jinxcat did you get a look in at the final answer? I know you love this kind of stuff :)

Comment: @NeilLunn thanx for the heads up :) I have to say, good job! +1ed

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Querying this structure for the results you want is not possible without knowing all of the possible `forms` names beforehand, and using them in the query. It would be very messy at any rate. That said, read on as I explain how it can be done.

There is a problem with the structure of these documents that is going to prevent you doing any reasonable query analysis. As it stands you would have to know all the possible form name fields in order to filter out anything.

Your current structure has forms containing a sub-document, of which each key contains another sub-document with a single property, `status`. This is difficult to traverse as your `forms` element has an arbitrary structure for each document you create. That means the pattern to *descend* to the `status` information you want to compare changes for every document in your collection.

Here is what I mean by path. To get at status in any element you have to do the following

> Forms -> **PreOp** -> status
>
> Forms -> **Alert** -> status

With the second element changing all the time. There is **no way** to *wildcard* something like this as the naming is considered explicit.

This may have been considered an easy way to implement serializing the data from your *forms* but I see a **more flexible** alternative. What you need is a document structure you can traverse in a standard pattern. This is always something worth considering in design. Take the following:

```js
{
    "_id" : "Tvq444454j",
    "name": "Jim",
    "forms": [
        {
             "name": "Jorney",
             "status":"closed"          
        },
        {
            "name": "Women",
            "status":"void"            
        },
        {
            "name": "Child",
            "status":"closed"           
        },
        {
            "name": "Farm",
            "status":"closed"            
        }  
    ]
}
```

So the structure of the document is changed to make the `forms` element an Array, and rather than place the status field under a key that names the "form field" we have each member of the Array as a sub-document cotaining the "form field" `name` and the `status`. So both the identifier and the status are still paired together but just represented as a sub-document now. This most importantly changes the access path to these keys, as now for **both** the field name and it's status we can do

> Forms -> **status**
>
> or
>
> Forms -> **name**

What **this** means is that you can query to find the names of all the fields in the `form` or all the  `status` fields in the `form`, or even all the documents with a certain `name` field and certain `status`. That is **much** better than what could be done with the original structure.

Now in your particular case, you want to get **only** the documents where **all** the fields are not `void`. Now there is no way in a single query to do this as there is no operator to compare all the elements in a an array in this way and see if they are the same. But there are two approaches you can take:

The first and probably not as efficient is to query for **all** documents that contain an element in `forms` that has a `status` of "void". With the resulting document Id's you can issue another query that returns the documents that do **not** have the Id's that were specified.

```js
db.forms.find({ "forms.status": "void" },{ _id: 1})

db.forms.find({ _id: $not: { $in: [<Object1>,<Object2>,<Object3>,... ] } })
```

Given result size this may not be possible and is generally not a good idea as the exclusion operator `$not` is basically forcing a *full scan* of the collection, so you couldn't use an index.

Another approach is to use the aggregation pipeline as follows:

```js
db.forms.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$forms" },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "status": { "$addToSet": "$forms.status" }}},
    { "$unwind": "$status" },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "status": -1 }},
    { "$group": { "_id": "$_id", "status": { "$first": "$status"}}},
    { "$match":{ "status": "closed" }}
])
```

Of course that will only return the _id for the documents that match, but you can issue a query with $in and return the whole matching documents. This is better than the exclusion operator used before, and now we can use an index to avoid full collection scans.

As a final approach and for the **best** performance consideration, you could change the document again so that at the top level you keep the "status" of whether any field in the forms in "void" or "closed". So at the top level the value would be closed only if all the items were "closed" and "void" if something were void, and so on.

That final one would mean a further programmatic change, and all changes to the `forms` items would need to update this field as well to maintain the "status". It is however the most efficient way of finding the documents you need and may be worth consideration.

---

**EDIT**:

Aside from changing the document to have a master status, fastest query form on the revised structure is actually:

```js
db.forms.find({ "forms": { "$not": { "$elemMatch": { "status": "void" } } } })
```

Comment: One thing I did omit (facepalm) when using the aggregation approach you can **$project** the entire document as the `_id` as it is unique already and that is the key for grouping. That way, by adding a final **$project** and re-establishing the keys from `_id` in the original form you can restore the document(s) to the original state and remove the need to issue another query using the `_id` key(s). Forgot because I'm too used to transforming in aggregation.

Comment: thanks you a lot. I spent a lot of time to searching such approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the original structure, and you need it inside an aggregation pipeline, you can use `$objectToArray`, in order to replace the unknown key with a known one like this:

1. `$objectToArray` to create known keys.
2. create an array of all statuses `formsData`
3. `$filter` `formsData` and count the number of `void` in the array as `voidCount`
4. `$match` only documents with `voidCount: 0`
5. foramt

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {formsData: {$objectToArray: "$forms"}}},
  {$set: {formsData: "$formsData.v.status"}},
  {
    $set: {
      voidCount: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$formsData",
            as: "item",
            cond: {$eq: ["$$item", "void"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {voidCount: 0}},
  {$unset: ["voidCount", "formsData"]}
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1coHj0t29_B)