# Get only selective column in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

Display only selective columns in collection

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("52f4a5ed07b0f7106a9d5e4c"),
   "FM_ID":"1253",
   "passwd": ".aDoSkljf_h+6589q76w3rJK",
   "Area": {
        "0": {
                "X": "53543500",
                "Y": "14031500",
                "images": {
                            "0": {
                                    "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1a84"),
                                    "ImageType": NumberInt(15) 
                                },
                            "1": {
                                    "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1a87"),
                                    "ImageType": NumberInt(2) 
                                }
                            } 
            },
        "1": {

                "X": "53543500",
                "Y": "14094572",
                "images": {
                            "0": {
                                    "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1aa8"),
                                    "ImageType": NumberInt(15) 
                                },
                            "1": {
                                    "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1aab"),
                                    "ImageType": NumberInt(2) 
                                }

                            } 
                },
        "2": {
                "X": "53480464",
                "Y": "14031500",
                "images": {
                            "0": {
                                    "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1acc"),
                                    "ImageType": NumberInt(15) 
                                }
                            } 
            }

        }
}
```

I want to display only selective data in collection

BasicDBObject have following fields

```
    B.append("FM_ID", 1);
    B.append("_id", 1);
    B.append("Area.$.$.images$.$.ImageType", 1);
```

My requirement is only display the FM_ID,_id,and ImageType

Comment: Note that you have multiple `images` within multiple `Area` fields. Is there one that you want to get or **all** of them

Comment: Yes My need is only filter the particular image based upon the image type. The Area also collection in that each object have this X,Y variable and Images Collection [ in images have many Image Object each Image object have Image ID and image Type ] can you tell how to design the scheme and filter only the matching Image Type data of ( FM ID,_id,Image Type)

Comment: Okay, Good. I kind of went with that in the answer, yet also the partial aggregation statement would put things into a state where you can filter on both of your nested arrays as I put in the Schema redesign. Take a look at the sample document there and read the linked post. The $unwind statements used are possible because the fields no-longer contain static sub-documents but arrays. Much more flexible. Follow the $match link and play with the sample document.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the projection of fields, you should pass the DBObject for projection,

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query, projectionQuery);
```

The projection is The DBObject in form of key-value pair. where,

key is the name of field you want to project. value can be either 0 or 1.
0 - means exclude the particular column from result set.
1 - means include the particular column in result set.

For more info, see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).

You can limit the fields tobe returned from an array using '**elemMatch**' from **projection query**.

For more [info](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).

Comment: This type of projection will not work. The question says (though not well) **only** those three fields. There is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your schema is almost certainly not what you want to be able to query in any meaningful way. Everything is in sub-documents with 'pseudo-numeric' keys, and that's a sure sign that you actually want arrays and you **do** want them.

So, I'll consider the rest of the answer on that you absolutely change the format of your schema as shown in the below example. The reasons for this I went to some length to explain in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639060/2313887).

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("52f4a5ed07b0f7106a9d5e4c"),
    "FM_ID":"1253",
    "passwd": ".aDoSkljf_h+6589q76w3rJK",
    "Area": [
        {
            "X": "53543500",
            "Y": "14031500",
            "images": [
                {
                    "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1a84"),
                    "ImageType": NumberInt(15) 
                },
                {
                    "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1a87"),
                    "ImageType": NumberInt(2) 
                }
             ]
        },
        {

            "X": "53543500",
            "Y": "14094572",
            "images": [
                 {
                     "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1aa8"),
                     "ImageType": NumberInt(15) 
                 },
                 {
                     "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1aab"),
                     "ImageType": NumberInt(2) 
                 }
             ]
         },
         { 
             "X": "53480464",
             "Y": "14031500",
             "images": [
                 {
                     "ImgId": ObjectId("52f4a5a107b0f7106a9d1acc"),
                     "ImageType": NumberInt(15) 
                 }
              ] 
          }

     ]
 }
```

Now with this we can do many more meaningful things, as was covered in the other answer. But for this one, since you have not told us a lot more than this, we can retrieve the data as just the three fields you mention ( _id, FM_ID, ImageType ).

As this cannot be done in standard query projection and since you likely want to **match** certain values, the best approach is to run through the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). There's plenty of Java documentation on this (all just DBObject anyway) but this is the standard shell form:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$Area" },
    {$project: { FM_ID: 1, ImageType: "$Area.images.ImageType" }},
    {$unwind: "$ImageType"}
])
```

So this way we get **only** the three fields that you want in your response.

If you are looking for specific entries out of the document(s) structure, look at the [**$match**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) pipeline operator.