# MongoDB Mongoose dynamic fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing a website in which each user has a number of balances for different currencies. Throughout the lifetime of the website I will regularly add new currencies.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store the balances using mongoose. I currently atore the balances like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    balances: {
        mck: {
            type: Number,
            default: 100.0,
            addresses: String
        },
        btc:{
            type: Number,
            default: 10.0,
            address: String
        }
    }

});
```

But it doesn't seem like the best approach. each time I want to add a new currency the existing documents will not contain it. **Are there disadvantages to allowing documents in the database which are out of sync with the schema?**

I thought of making the schema more dynamic by using a subdocument to store currencies and their respective balances like this:

```
var BalanceSchema = new Schema({
    currency: String,
    amount: Number,
    address: String
});
```

But there would be a painful number of callbacks to deal with when changing balances etc.

**Which of these methods would be the best approach? Or is there another I have missed?**

Comment: How fields are stored is usually driven off of how you plan on doing queries later. Also, be careful with money and the `number`. You may loose precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the need to add currencies dynamically in the future, you should opt to have "balances" as an array.

```
balances: [
    {
    curr: "mck",
    bal: 123,45
    },
    {
    curr: "btc",
    bal: 42
    }
]
```

It helps with queries in the future ([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623979/mongodb-aggregation-framework-match-by-nested-documents#comment32776032_21623979)) and it also gives you **a lot** of flexibility with each document.

Or why not go for a flat schema like:

```
{
user: "user1",
currency1balance:54,76,
currency5balance:1024
}
```

Comment: The thing is there seems to be no easy way to get access to the balances other than querying them every time - this means I have to query the user first & things get really messy, unless I have some global getBalance function, but I don't really want that. On the client side I can easily access balances using the first approach.

Comment: How about a flat schema like the above? Each user doesn't need to have a balance in all currencies