# How to Structure Time-Series model in django-mongodb-engine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models, django-mongodb-engine

I'm trying to define a time-series model in django using mongodb as the backend. I read about some [best practices for timeseries data at the MongoDB Blog](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb), and I think I understand it well enough. But now, my problem/question is: how do I define such a model using django's model syntax? I'm not sure if these would be `embedded documents` or simply storing `arrays` or `dicts` in the model field. Here is the suggested mongo format:

ideal mongo document format:

```
{
  timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:00:00.000Z"),
  type: “memory_used”,
  values: {
    0: { 0: 999999, 1: 999999, …, 59: 1000000 },
    1: { 0: 2000000, 1: 2000000, …, 59: 1000000 },
    …,
    58: { 0: 1600000, 1: 1200000, …, 59: 1100000 },
    59: { 0: 1300000, 1: 1400000, …, 59: 1500000 }
  }
}
```

One solution is to do something like this, a document holds a day's worth of data:

```
# models.py
class timeseries(models.Model):
    date            = models.DateField(null=True)
    value_hour_0    = models.CharField(max_length='1024', blank=True)
    value_hour_1    = models.CharField(max_length='1024', blank=True)
    value_hour_...
    value_hour_23   = models.CharField(max_length='1024', blank=True)
```

Even if I store `arrays` or `dicts` in the `value_hour_n` field, it doesn't quite offer the advantages of querying the document as mentioned in the article, for example as `timeseries.HR.MIN`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't disagree more on the structure being an *ideal* format, and I always seem to see this kind of notation used as a 'PHP understanding' of how to model an array, but this does not suit a Mongo interpretation.

For reasons in which I went into much more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639060/2313887), I generally find the the following structure is more flexible for query purposes:

```
{
  timestamp_hour: ISODate("2013-10-10T23:00:00.000Z"),
  type: “memory_used”,
  values: [
    [ 999999, 999999, …, 1000000 ],
    [ 2000000, 2000000, …, 1000000 ],
    …,
    [ 1600000, 1200000, …, 1100000 ],
    [ 1300000, 1400000, …, 1500000 ]
  ]
}
```

That way (as explained in the other answer) you are not tied to specifically addressing any part of the path to get to any element. The sub-document notation is *one-way* and you have to fully specify each one, cannot do *ranges* of things or find values at different positions.

Using arrays you are going to get the positional notation for **free** anyway, so you can `values.59` or even `values.20.15` if you want to, or otherwise match on keys within documents, *in the array*.

For your solution, you would need to play around with that more, but this and the other reading gives the general gist.

Answer (score 0):

you can do what you wrote,but what if you wanted to store values every 2 hours or every 30min ? so it's not a good practice

what about this :

```
class MyModelStat(models.Model):
    #other fields like : nbr_views, nbr_clicks, rates ...
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name="stats")
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    previous = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
    current_stats = self.my_model.current_stats
    if current_stats is not None and self.id is None:
        #iterate over the fields, and do your stuff
        self.rates = current_stats.rates + 1 
        self.nbr_views = current_stats.nbr_views
        #set the current stat as the previous for the new stat
        self.previous = self.deal.current_stats
    super(MyModelStat, self).save(**kwargs)



@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModelStat)
def set_mymodel_stats(sender, *args, **kwargs):
"""
Signal handler to ensure that a new stats is always chosen as the current stats - automatically. It simplifies stuff
greatly. Also stores previous revision for diff-purposes
"""
instance = kwargs['instance']
created = kwargs['created']
if created and instance.my_model:
    instance.my_model.current_stats = instance
    instance.my_model.save()
```