# Searching a set of documents nested in another document

Tags: mongodb

I have an interesting problem at work. We have a document structure like this:

```
{
"q" : "c1179beb-2db4-4052-b10d-f0c1332436f3",
"ssm" : {
    "0168edb0-c25d-42ba-ba6d-918c4f61f6e1" : {
        "xas" : [],
        "dob" : ISODate("2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "we" : "bow-bq",
        "gndr" : "M",
        "lcd" : ISODate("2014-02-21T09:00:04.575Z"),
        "re" : "tyjhgj",
        "s" : "0168edb0-c25d-42ba-ba6d-918c4f61f6e1",
        "scsv" : "testdata",
        "sg" : {
            "grd" : "FOUR",
            "gdn" : "4"
        },
        "sno" : "100000002",
        "sss" : "Ha",
        "stst" : {
            "tk" : "226",
            "tn" : "That"
        },
        "tsd" : ISODate("2014-02-21T08:35:51.075Z")
    },
    "016e48fa-5c24-4fd5-b078-5333991de013" : {
        "xas" : [],
        "dob" : ISODate("2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "we" : "dsgsdf",
        "gndr" : "M",
        "lcd" : ISODate("2014-02-21T09:04:11.995Z"),
        "lia" : 53,
        "re" : "ghjghjgh",
        "s" : "016e48fa-5c24-4fd5-b078-5333991de013",
        "scsv" : "testdata",
        "sg" : {
            "grd" : "FOUR",
            "gdn" : "4"
        },
        "sno" : "100000029",
        "sss" : "Ha",
        "stst" : {
            "tk" : "86",
            "tn" : "That"
        },
        "tsd" : ISODate("2014-02-21T08:50:55.821Z")
    },
    "076fc7ab-264b-4814-9f3a-db9f8222d02f" : {
        "xas" : [],
        "dob" : ISODate("2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "we" : "hjhyyio",
        "gndr" : "M",
        "lcd" : ISODate("2014-02-21T09:04:58.299Z"),
        "lia" : 53,
        "re" : "qsdrfg",
        "s" : "076fc7ab-264b-4814-9f3a-db9f8222d02f",
        "scsv" : "testdata",
        "sg" : {
            "grd" : "FOUR",
            "gdn" : "4"
        },
        "sno" : "100000003",
        "sss" : "HA",
        "stst" : {
            "tk" : "161",
            "tn" : "That"
        },
        "tsd" : ISODate("2014-02-21T08:52:04.471Z")
    },
"try" : "34534",
"jyu" : ISODate("2014-03-01T07:59:59.000Z"),
"poij" : ISODate("2014-01-08T08:00:00.000Z")

}
}
```

Obviously this is data that has been edited to hide the source but the structure is the same.

I am trying to write a query that will search on the "s" field of the sub-documents contained in the sub-document "ssm".

I have tried using $elementmatch as well as using standard dot notation. The issue I am running into is that the "ssm" field is more of a sub-collection than a sub-document. I'm a little lost and am hoping for a few suggestions.

Reading the Mongo documentation I can't seem to find any way to query sub-collections. Google shows me plenty of ways to query an ARRAY of sud-documents but that is not what I'm dealing with here.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are aware, your listed items are sub-documents and not members of an array. As such you have **no** way of referencing the underlying values without knowing the composition of the keys in the levels of nesting.

I reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21639060/2313887) of mine a bit, all on the same topic, so probably worth a read. But the data structure here is greatly flawed if you want to do any kind of meaningful query analysis on it. As such it **should** be changed and the other answer and your own findings should be compelling reasons to do so.

There is no simple solution to dealing with a structure like this, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2298870/2313887) and answer may give some insight into how to "discover" the key names in order to feed to query information. But that will be a laborious process.

A good strength of MongoDB is that it allows you to **change** things with a lot more flexibility than a relational setup. The flexibility in document design **also** gives you "enough rope to hang yourself", and re-design is often a necessity over the evolution of your development.

Get the structure changed to something that works.

Comment: Thanks! You confirmed my suspicions. I agree that the structure is fundamentally wrong and I am not quite sure why it was designed that way. Unfortunately that decision was way above my pay grade. I will continue to try to point out the flaws in the design and hopefully someone will listen. With that said, I have not tried using the unwind function as you do in your other answer. I will give that a try and see if I can cobble something together. Eventually I will most likely fall back on my tried and true python/pymongo combo to unscrew the structure of the collections. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
{
"q" : "c1179beb-2db4-4052-b10d-f0c1332436f3",
"ssm" : {
    "0168edb0-c25d-42ba-ba6d-918c4f61f6e1" : {
        "dob" : ISODate("2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        },
    },
    "016e48fa-5c24-4fd5-b078-5333991de013" : {
        "dob" : ISODate("2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
{
"q" : "c1179beb-2db4-4052-b10d-f0c1332436f3",
"ssm" : [
          {
           "name": "0168edb0-c25d-42ba-ba6d-918c4f61f6e1",
           "dob" : ISODate("2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
          },
          {
           "name": "016e48fa-5c24-4fd5-b078-5333991de013",
           "dob" : ISODate("2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
          }
 ],
 "foo": "bar"
}
```

That way, you can search for documents where *someone* has a DOB via `find(ssm.dob: date)`. Once you find your document, you'll still have to scan the sub-documents to see which one matched.

If you don't like that, you'll need to create each `someone` as a document in a different collection.

Comment: I agree that  the structure is wrong. if I had it my way i would change it. Unfortunately that is not my decision. Thank you for the example of what it should look like though!